# tasks with balls and buckets

Tags: combinatorics

We have p identical balls and buckets. We want to know how many ways we can deploy in these buckets. Is my solution good? Why not, why yes (please confirm)?
$$ \frac {w ^ p} {p!}$$
For each ball assigns a bucket, and because they are indistinguishable I divide by the number of permutations of the set.

Comment: What is $w$? Explain.

Comment: I'm sorry. w is number of buckets

Comment: what if there were $p$ balls and one bucket? Then your formula would say there were $\frac{1}{p!}$ partitions, which clearly makes no sense, as the answer should always be 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of ways to distribute $p$ identical balls among $p$ identical buckets is the number of [partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) of $p$. There is no nice formula for this number.  There is no nice formula for the number of partitions of $p$ into at most $w$ parts either.

Comment: ok, so what is the answer I can write?

Comment: The Wikipedia article *The Twelvefold Way* has a thorough discussion of all problems in this family. Together with the partitions article I referred to, it will let you give recurrences for your problem.

Comment: Mr Andre, thanks a lot! :)